# laravel SMTP mail

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I am trying to send the mail using smpt on google mail
my .env file is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MYEmailAddress
MAIL_PASSWORD=MyPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and the server code is

```
try {
        Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($completeView,$emailAdress) {
            $message->to($emailAdress, $emailAdress)->subject("Property List");
            $message->from("Myemail", "info")->setBody($completeView, 'text/html');
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return array([$e->getMessage(),"Myemail"]);
    }
```

I also enable the Less secure app access in gmail
and the response I get from the server is

> Expected response code 250 but got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Comment: still getting error Expected response code 250 but got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Comment: Please put information about response code to question itself by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you are using gmail address to sent mail. then you need to on less secure app.

   go to https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

   then allow by turning it on.

   and also use php artisan config:clear
2. sometimes google blocks when you try to send email through some code. In that case you got a alert mail. click on that mail(Check Activity) and mark as yes (Do you recognize this activity?)
3. Or you can try MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail and also use php artisan config:clear

Comment: I tried with **2 way authentication** create an app named Laravel then generate the key
`
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MYEmailAddress
MAIL_PASSWORD=generatedPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
`
still getting the same response Expected response code 250 but got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Also add php artisan config:clear in the deployment script

Comment: Fixed the issue. I am pushing _.env_ file but is not updated buy laravel forge. Manullay update the _.env_ file. now mail is working