# can't send mail from Laravel in live server

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, cpanel

I have a live project in my GoDaddy server. I am trying to send an email after submitting a form and for that I have configured `.env` and `mail.php` file. But mail is not send and more over that **no error file shown in `log` file**.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='app_specific_password'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**controller**

```
Mail::send('mail', $emailDataArray, function($message) use ($emailDataArray)
{
    $message->to('info@gmail.com')->subject('New Online Estimate');
    $message->from('nfo@gmail.com');
});
```

Mail is not send and no error shown in `log` file.
Anybody Help Please ? I am in serious problem

Comment: in godaddy you cant use gmail i guess, you can able to use only godaddy email

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj... I actuall want that for godaddy email.. but for that same reason happen. Now I tried with gmail for testing purpose

Comment: even i have lot of issue with email and godaddy, call for godaddy support they will help you.

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj....  Any other way do you know ?

Comment: probably no, issue is on their side, ask them to upload their code and check on the server, if it is not working they have to release port

Comment: Hello @Raff Hope this will help you [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035139/how-to-send-mail-with-laravel-through-gmail-smtp/54035212#54035212)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code, problem is in the Webmail.
Consult with the server customer center and Now it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate third party apps on gmail? if no then, [go this link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) , turn on '**Change account access for less secure apps**' option

It may be fix your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967886/laravel-smtp-mail/54967989